# USB Bus sometimes not listed in lsusb

Tags: debian, usb, lsusb

I have a problem with my APU4D4. It has 3 onboard USB bus, that we use for internal LTE and WLAN card, and two external USB bus. Sometime the two external bus are not detected and do not show up in lsusb either

```
root@Boje2:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1199:9091 Sierra Wireless, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1546:01a8 U-Blox AG [u-blox 8]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If it boots it looks like this

```
root@Boje2:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1199:9091 Sierra Wireless, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1546:01a8 U-Blox AG [u-blox 8]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0403:d011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd SCS Position-Tracker/TNC
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05e3:0604 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 1.1 Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2341:8057 Arduino SA
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is it possible to rescan the USB bus?